# Understanding `_mm_prefetch`

Tags: c++, performance, intrinsics, micro-optimization, prefetch

The answer [What are _mm_prefetch() locality hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521694/what-are-mm-prefetch-locality-hints) goes into details on what the hint means.

My question is: which one do I **WANT**?

I work on a function that is called repeatedly, billions of times, with some `int` parameter among others. First thing I do is to look up some cached value using that parameter (its low 32 bits) as a key into 4GB cache. Based on the algorithm from where this function is called, I know that most often that key will be doubled (shifted left by 1 bit) from one call to the next, so I am doing:

```
int foo(int key) {
  uint8_t value = cache[key];
  _mm_prefetch((const char *)&cache[key * 2], _MM_HINT_T2);
  // ...
```

The goal is to have this `value` in a processor cache by the next call to this function.

I am looking for confirmation on my understanding of two points:

1. The call to `_mm_prefetch` is not going to delay the processing of the instructions immediately following it.
2. There is no penalty for pre-fetching wrong location, just a lost benefit from guessing it right.

That function is using a lookup table of 128 128-bit values (2 KB total). Is there a way to “force” it to be cached? The index into that lookup table is incremented sequentially; should I pre-fetch them too? I should probably use another hint, to point to another level of cache? What is the best strategy here?

Comment: Well, regarding (2), there is a potential penalty for pre-fetching the wrong location, since you thereby evict something else from the cache.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 - I understand; but I only read from memory in these two cases: my `cache` and that lookup table; everything else is in local variables. Can I somehow direct one of them to L1 and another to L2? Am I naive?

Comment: Well, recall that reads/writes to your thread's stack (e.g. local variables) also use the cache, since the CPU and memory bus don't distinguish between that and heap.  So if you prefetch something wrong, some stack locals could be evicted.  Sorry, I don't have an answer to your other question :-)

Comment: you might want to use ```_MM_HINT_T0``` so it prefetches to L1 cache

Comment: @Noah - thank you! But `T0` says `All cache levels` - so it would trash (evict) everything! I thought I tried that before, with less success. But will try again, and report here

Comment: @Noah the time difference between various cache hints was within the noise :(

Comment: @VladFeinstein what is the delay between the prefetch and when the memory is loaded. Also if this is always called a billion times in a row you might consider streaming the inputs and prefetching the future calls. see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9tlJAqMV7U

Comment: @Noah I call `_mm_prefetch` immediately after I consumed the previous key; the rest of the function is taking significant time (compared to even uncached read).

Comment: "But T0 says All cache levels" that is how it is on Intel, the caches are inclusive the data that is in L1 is present in L2 and the data that is present in L2 is in L3.

Answer (score 5):

As I noted in the comments, there's some risk to prefetching the wrong address - a useful address will be evicted from the cache, potentially causing a cache miss.

That said:

`_mm_prefetch` compiles into the `PREFETCHn` instruction.  I looked up the instruction in the [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf) published by AMD.  (Note that all of this information is necessarily chipset specific; you may need to find your CPU's docs).

AMD says (my emphasis):

> The operation of this instruction is implementation-dependent. The processor implementation can ignore or change this instruction. The size of the cache line also depends on the implementation, with a minimum size of 32 bytes. **AMD processors alias PREFETCH1 and PREFETCH2 to PREFETCH0**

What that appears to mean is that if you're running on an AMD, then the hint is ignored, and the memory is loaded into the all levels of the cache -- *unless* it's a hint that it's a NTA (Non-Temporal-Access, attempts to load memory with minimal cache pollution).

Here's the full page for the instruction

[image: Prefetch]

I think in the end, the guidance is what the other answer says: brainstorm, implement, test, and measure.  You're on the bleeding edge of perf here, and there's not going to be a one size fits all answer.

Another resource that may help you is [Agner Fog's Optimization manuals](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#manuals), which will help you optimize for your specific CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the references!

Answer (score 4):

If you do anything related to performance, the best and ultimate way to know what you need is to try it. Fortunately, you know exactly what to try, and there are just a few possibilities.

Regarding your understanding — yes, it is correct. However, there is a cost to anything (e.g. if you add any instruction to your code, the processor will waste a nanosecond executing it). You should verify your idea of prefetching by measuring the performance before and after. For very irregular access patterns, it is very likely to work.

Regarding prefetching any sequential data — you should probably not bother. Caches hold data at 64-byte granularity, so for sequential data, prefetching will usually not help. In addition, some (all?) caches have predictive loading — they prefetch ahead even when not told to.

Comment: Thank you! I am in fact trying, many things. Would help to have a general strategy... For example, how do I know what will be in L1 and L2 caches? And do I have control over it? I do understand the meaning of `hint` in `_MM_HINT_T2` :)