# Explicit memory prefetching for Intel Compilers

Tags: vectorization, simd, avx2, prefetch, intel-oneapi

I have two functions, one which calculates the difference between successive elements of a row and the second calculates the successive difference between values in a column. Therefore one would calculate `M[i][j+1] -M[i][j]` and second would do `M[i+1][j] - M[i][j]`, `M` being the matrix. I implement them as follows -

```
inline void firstFunction(uchar* input, uchar* output, size_t M, size_t N){

    for(int i=0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j=0; j <=N - 33; j+=32){

            auto pos = i*N + j;
            _mm256_storeu_epi8(output + pos, _mm256_sub_epi8(_mm256_loadu_epi8(input + pos + 1), _mm256_loadu_epi8(input + pos)));   
        
        }
    }
}
```

```
void secondFunction(uchar* input, uchar* output, size_t M, size_t N){

    for(int i = 0; i < M-1; i++){
//#pragma prefetch input : (i+1)*N : (i+1)*N + N
        for(int j = 0; j <N-33; j+=32){

            auto idx = i * N + j;
            auto idx_1 = (i+1)*N + j;

            _mm256_storeu_epi8(output + idx, _mm256_sub_epi8(_mm256_loadu_epi8(input + idx_1), _mm256_loadu_epi8(input + idx)));
        }
    }
```

However, Benchmarking them, Average runtimes for the first and second function are as follows - 
`firstFunction = 21.1432ms` 
`secondFunction = 166.851ms`

Where the size of matrix is `M = 9024` and `N = 12032`

This is a huge increase in the runtime for a similar operation. I suspect this has something to do with memory accesses and caching, where way more cycles are spent in getting the memory from another row in the second case.

So my question is two-part.

1. Is my reasoning for the difference in runtimes correct.
2. How do I alleviate it. My first idea is to prefetch the second row in the memory and go ahead, but I am not able to prefetch a dynamically calculated position. Would `_mm_prefetch` help if the issue is indeed of the memory access times

I am using the `dpcpp` compiler. with compile options as `-g -O3 -fsycl  -fsycl-targets=spir64 -mavx512f -mavx512vl -mavx512bw -qopenmp -liomp5 -lpthread`. This compiler has a `pragma prefetch` but it does not allow runtime calculated prefetches. However, I would really appreciate something which is not specific to the compiler and it could also be spefic to GCC.

Edit1 - Just tried `_mm_prefetch`, but that too throws `error: argument to 'error: argument to '__builtin_prefetch' must be a constant integer _mm_prefetch(input + (i+1) * N, N);`. So an additional question, is there any way we can prefetch runtime calculated memory locations ?

TIA

Comment: I suspect conflict eviction from cache. `N = 12032` is `0x2F00` Try making N in your array `N = 12064` (`0x2F20`) to see if the results are better? (Just don't use these extra elements)

Comment: `_mm_prefetch` takes one pointer, the second arg is `_MM_HINT_T0` for you, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46521694/2945027

Comment: @AlexGuteniev, My knowledge is rather nascent in this domain. Could you please elaborate or point to a resource about conflict eviction. Also I would try with 10264, but this code would go somewhere else, where matrix dimensions would not be in my hand, so would not padding a matrix nullify the benefits from SIMD ?

Comment: You could try some sort of blocking, e.g. `for(int jj=0; jj<N; jj+=256) for(int i = 0; i < M-1; i++) for(int j=jj; j<jj+256; j+=32) {...}` (Not sure what the best blocksize is on your CPU and you probably need to fix the edge cases). That way the input needs to be read only once into L1 cache -- if you completely unroll the inner loop and have enough registers available, you could even save half the loads).

Comment: From https://www.agner.org/optimize/ get *Optimizing software in C++* (optimizing_cpp.pdf), look into chapters  _9.2 Cache organization_  _9.10 Cache contentions in large data structures_ , they specifically discuss cache and matrices.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev, sure I will go through it, thanks so much

Comment: @chtz, thanks for your response. Could you please  elaborate a little more, especially about the order of your operations and why that increment by 256?

Comment: Try disabling the optimization and check whether this helps. instead of -O3 use -Od flag option.